# Errors: Error:(19, 9) error: return outside method / Error:(24, 35) error: cannot find symbol method nextFact()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm just starting out with Android Studio and following a tutorial on Youtube to try and slowly work out how things work but I seem to have some errors in my code so I can't run it.

**The error for my Facts.java is:**
Error:(19, 9) error: return outside method

**The errors for my MainActivity.java is:**
Error:(24, 35) error: cannot find symbol method nextFact()
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I've tried looking around but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any assistance would be great. I'm pretty new to this so I'm sorry if this is a stupid issue to have.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView factBox;
Facts factHolder = new Facts();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    factBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextBox);
}

public void genFact(View view)
{
    factBox.setText(factHolder.nextFact());
}
}
```

**Facts.java:**

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;



public class Facts {
String Facts [] = {
        "This is Fact 1",
        "This is fact 2",
        "This is fact 3",
};

int i = 0;

public String nextFact[];
{
    i++;
    return facts[i];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Facts class with bellow

```
 public class Facts {
  String facts [] = {
    "This is Fact 1",
    "This is fact 2",
    "This is fact 3",
 };

 int i = 0;

 public String nextFact()
{
   i++;
  return facts[i];
}
}
```

Comment: Ah that seems to have fixed it! Thank you very much for your help